# different kind of timeouts in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Sql jobs integrate our applications.We have lot of sql jobs running parellely at any given point of time.We have some P0 sql jobs which are failing intermittently with below errors.

1."Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

2.Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired"

3.ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {87F25D2D-68B5-40D8-A858-F82291B73ECA} with the following error message: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\

4.Semaphore timeout expired

We are seeing this timeouts rarely(once on two days minimum),but business is not in a position to accept this rate.

From our side,we have tried checking with network,storage and server team,every time we get all is well answer.

We even have monitors to check tempdb usage,long running queries,locks,wait stats.But we are not able to get any usefull info with this.CPU and Memory never exceeds 80%.

Can some one please help me with below info,if you have came across this in your environments
1.How to start troubleshooting this errors or at least in good position to say for example

this query waited for this much time to acquire connection and it failed beacuse it was not able to acquire connection due to...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Low-frequency occurences of this sort of issue are fairly common and usually impossible to completely eliminate.

I would edit the SQL Server Agent Step definitions to get them to retry a few times (e.g. 3) after a short interval (e.g. 5 minutes).  You want whatever temporary resource/network issue to be resolved but you also dont want to keep retrying indefinitely.

I would pitch this to "the business" as a pragmatic "fault tolerant" design, rather than aiming for perfection.

Comment: We did that,it is actually helping in reducing escalations.

Answer (score 0):

They ALL appear to be network related errors, so now that you've taken the heat off with Mike Honeys advice you should focus on troubleshooting the network.